# Cannot set default application for xdg-open

Tags: xdg, xdg-open

I am trying to make gthumb the default when opening png files from the terminal

```
$ xdg-mime default ~/.gnome/apps/gthumb.desktop image/png
```

I created this symlink:

```
$ ls -l ~/.gnome/apps/gthumb.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 gauthier gauthier 15 Jun 27 /home/gauthier/.gnome/apps/gthumb.desktop -> /usr/bin/gthumb
```

I expect `xdg-mime query default image/png` to return `gthumb`. Instead, it says:

```
$ xdg-mime query default image/png
eog.desktop
```

Why doesn't setting default have the effect I expect?

Answer (score 2):

Enabling debugging with the environment variable `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL` helped:

```
$ XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime default ~/.gnome/apps/gthumb.desktop 
image/png
make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
make_default_generic /home/gauthier/.gnome/apps/gthumb.desktop image/png
Updating /home/gauthier/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
$ XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default image/png
Checking /home/gauthier/.config/mimeapps.list
eog.desktop
```

The `mimeapps.list` used for setting vs reading defaults is not the same.
Solution (thanks to a comment [here](https://superuser.com/q/962687/28302)):

```
rm ~/.config/mimeapps.list
```