# Cannot set Brave as default xdg-open browser in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, kde, browser, defaults

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 with KDE Plasma. I have recently switched from Google Chrome to the Brave Browser, version (taken from `brave://settings/help`) `1.34.81 Chromium: 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, installed from the [Brave repos](https://brave.com/linux/).

I have set my default browser as Brave in the KDE options.
`xdg-open`, however, keeps opening URLS with Chrome.

Whenever I open the KDE default application settings, this is the settings I see, as if it did not manage to set the default, no matter if I used the "following application" or "following command" setting: [image]

Additional things I tried:

- `sensible-browser` and `x-www-browser` both correctly open Brave, not Chrome. Only `xdg-open` opens Chrome.
- `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default text/html` returns:

```
Running KDE trader query "text/html" mimetype and "Application" servicetype
google-chrome.desktop
```

- `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime default brave-browser.desktop text/html` returns (error code 0):

```
make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
make_default_generic brave-browser.desktop text/html
Updating /home/adriano/.config/mimeapps.list
```

- `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-settings set default-web-browser brave-browser.desktop` returns (with error code 4: the action failed, according to the manual):

```
Running KDE trader query "text/html" mimetype and "Application" servicetype
make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
make_default_generic brave-browser.desktop text/html
Updating /home/adriano/.config/mimeapps.list
Running KDE trader query "text/html" mimetype and "Application" servicetype
make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
make_default_generic google-chrome.desktop text/html
Updating /home/adriano/.config/mimeapps.list
```

- `sudo XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-settings set default-web-browser brave-browser.desktop` returns (with error code 0):

```
Checking /root/.config/mimeapps.list
make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
make_default_generic brave-browser.desktop text/html
Updating /root/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /root/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /root/.config/mimeapps.list
make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
make_default_generic brave-browser.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
Updating /root/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /root/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /root/.config/mimeapps.list
make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
make_default_generic brave-browser.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
Updating /root/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /root/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /root/.config/mimeapps.list
make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
make_default_generic brave-browser.desktop x-scheme-handler/about
Updating /root/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /root/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /root/.config/mimeapps.list
make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
make_default_generic brave-browser.desktop x-scheme-handler/unknown
Updating /root/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /root/.config/mimeapps.list
```

- The Chrome and Brave desktop files are OK. In fact, they are almost identical. This is the output of `diff /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop  /usr/share/applications/brave-browser.desktop`:

```
3c3
< Name=Google Chrome
---
> Name=Brave Web Browser
108c108
< Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
---
> Exec=/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable %U
111c111
< Icon=google-chrome
---
> Icon=brave-browser
114c114
< MimeType=application/pdf;application/rdf+xml;application/rss+xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xhtml_xml;application/xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;image/webp;text/html;text/xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
---
> MimeType=application/pdf;application/rdf+xml;application/rss+xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xhtml_xml;application/xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;image/webp;text/html;text/xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ipfs;x-scheme-handler/ipns;
169c169
< Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
---
> Exec=/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
221c221
< Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito
---
> Exec=/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable --incognito
```

- This is the output of `grep html ~/.config/mimeapps.list` (only brave is listed):

```
application/xhtml+xml=brave-browser.desktop;brave-browser.desktop;code.desktop;org.kde.kate.desktop;libreoffice-writer.desktop;okularApplication_txt.desktop;vim.desktop;firefox.desktop;
text/html=brave-browser.desktop;code.desktop;firefox.desktop;org.kde.kate.desktop;libreoffice-writer.desktop;rstudio.desktop;okularApplication_txt.desktop;vim.desktop;
application/xhtml+xml=brave-browser.desktop;
text/html=brave-browser.desktop
```

- manually editing `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` or updating the mime database as per [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565202/kde-is-not-saving-a-mime-type-file-association) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452174/cannot-set-default-application-for-xdg-open) to use Brave instead of Chrome does nothing.

Why can't I set Brave as default xdg-open browser?

On a similar Arch machine, none of this happens and everything works as expected.

I think the issue is probably in the `make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected` message, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your brave was installed from Discover or from its official website?

I was having the same problem as you, and I solved it by removing Brave (which had been installed from Discover) from my machine, and after that i installed Brave using the instructions from its website: https://brave.com/linux/.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a good path for me. I greatly prefer to install all available software from the repositories, which greatly simplifies maintenance.

Comment: @AF7 Installing Brave from the link he provided will make you add Brave's repositories, which get updates and security patches faster.

Comment: @telometto actually I see that I already did that, I forgot. Sorry. So I am already using Brave from the Brave repos, version `1.34.81 Chromium: 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. Still, the problem persists.

Comment: @AF7 Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452174/cannot-set-default-application-for-xdg-open) help?

Comment: @telometto see my answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687810/87677

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the solution was following the instructions found in [this SO answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/574766/87677).

The magic trick that did it for me, after manually editing the `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file, was manually updating KDE's mimetype cache using `kbuildsycoca5`.

This raised a warning:

```
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Parse error in  "/home/adriano/.config/menus/applications-merged/xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu" , line  1 , col  1 :  "unexpected end of file"
```

, but browser links now correctly open in Brave.

Comment: Perfect! Glad you found the solution.